Electron.js doesn't allow a second update until you switch different activity in laptop and return, which resets the update limit
Electron.js doesn't allow me to update 2nd time after the first update but it allows multiple update after switching to other tab and then get back to Electron.js app.
How can I solve this issue?
index.js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Temple Town Admin</title>

  <!-- Font Awesome for icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">

  <!-- External CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  
  <!-- Flatpickr CSS for date picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Top bar with admin greeting -->
    <div class="top-bar">
      <p>Welcome, Admin</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Header section with logo and heading -->
    <header>
      <div class="logo-section">
        <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="Temple Town Logo" class="logo">
        <h1 class="admin-heading">Admin Panel</h1>
      </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Search/filter section -->
    <section class="search-section">
      <div class="input-container">
        <label for="locationCode">Location Code:</label>
        <select id="locationCode"></select>
      </div>

      <div class="input-container">
        <label for="propertyCode">Property Code:</label>
        <select id="propertyCode"></select>
      </div>

      <div class="input-container">
        <label for="roomType">Room Type:</label>
        <select id="roomType"></select>
      </div>

      <!-- Start Date Picker -->
      <div class="input-container">
        <label for="startDate">Start Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="startDate" readonly>
      </div>

      <!-- End Date Picker -->
      <div class="input-container">
        <label for="endDate">End Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="endDate" readonly>
      </div>

      <!-- Button group for actions -->
      <div class="button-group">
        <button id="searchButton" class="btn primary-btn"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Search</button>
        <button id="refreshButton" class="btn secondary-btn"><i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i> Refresh</button>
        <button id="updateButton" class="btn danger-btn"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Update</button>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Table to display availability data -->
    <section class="availability-section">
      <table id="availabilityTable" class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Property Code</th>
            <th>Property Name</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Room Type</th>
            <th>Rooms Available</th>
            <th>Booked</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Max Count</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <!-- Data will be dynamically inserted here -->
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
  </div>

  <!-- JavaScript -->
  <script src="renderer.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
  <script>
    // Initialize Flatpickr for both date pickers
    flatpickr("#startDate", {
      dateFormat: "Y-m-d"
    });
    flatpickr("#endDate", {
      dateFormat: "Y-m-d"
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>


renderer.js
const API_BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api'; 

async function fetchDistinctValues() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/availabilities/distinct`);
    const data = await response.json();

    const locationCodeSelect = document.getElementById('locationCode');
    locationCodeSelect.innerHTML = `<option value="Any">Select Location</option>`;
    data.locationCodes.forEach(code => {
      locationCodeSelect.innerHTML += `<option value="${code}">${code}</option>`;
    });

    const roomTypeSelect = document.getElementById('roomType');
    roomTypeSelect.innerHTML = `<option value="Any">Select Room Type</option>`;
    data.roomTypes.forEach(type => {
      roomTypeSelect.innerHTML += `<option value="${type}">${type}</option>`;
    });

    const propertyCodeSelect = document.getElementById('propertyCode');
    propertyCodeSelect.innerHTML = `<option value="Any">Select Property</option>`;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching distinct values:', error);
  }
}

async function fetchPropertyCodesByLocation(locationCode) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/availabilities/property_codes?location_code=${locationCode}`);
    const data = await response.json();

    // Populate property codes for the selected location
    const propertyCodeSelect = document.getElementById('propertyCode');
    propertyCodeSelect.innerHTML = `<option value="Any">Select Property</option>`;
    data.propertyCodes.forEach(code => {
      propertyCodeSelect.innerHTML += `<option value="${code}">${code}</option>`;
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching property codes for location:', error);
  }
}

async function fetchAvailabilities(filters = {}) {
  try {
    const params = new URLSearchParams();

    if (filters.location_code && filters.location_code !== 'Any') {
      params.append('location_code', filters.location_code);
    }
    if (filters.property_code && filters.property_code !== 'Any') {
      params.append('property_code', filters.property_code);
    }
    if (filters.room_type && filters.room_type !== 'Any') {
      params.append('room_type', filters.room_type);
    }
    if (filters.dates && filters.dates.length > 0) {
      params.append('start_date', filters.dates[0]);
      params.append('end_date', filters.dates[1] || filters.dates[0]); 
    }

    const response = await fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/availabilities?${params.toString()}`);
    const data = await response.json();

    populateTable(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching availabilities:', error);
  }
}

function populateTable(data) {
  const tableBody = document.querySelector('table tbody');
  tableBody.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing table rows

  data.forEach(item => {
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.classList.add('editable-row');

    row.innerHTML = `
      <td class="date">${item.date}</td>
      <td class="property_code">${item.property_code}</td>
      <td class="property_name">${item.property_name}</td>
      <td class="location">${item.location_code}</td>
      <td class="room_type">${item.room_type}</td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="rooms_available">${item.rooms_available}</td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="booked">${item.booked}</td>
      <td contenteditable="true" class="price">${item.price}</td>
      <td class="max_count">${item.max_count}</td>
    `;

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
  });
  reapplyEditable();
}

function reapplyEditable() {
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr.editable-row');

  rows.forEach(row => {
    const editableCells = row.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable]');
    editableCells.forEach(cell => {
      cell.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true'); 
    });

    row.addEventListener('click', function () {
      row.classList.toggle('selected');
    });
  });
}
async function updateSelectedRows() {
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr.selected');
  const updates = [];

  rows.forEach(row => {
    const date = row.querySelector('.date').innerText;
    const location_code = row.querySelector('.location').innerText;
    const property_code = row.querySelector('.property_code').innerText;
    const room_type = row.querySelector('.room_type').innerText;
    const rooms_available = row.querySelector('.rooms_available').innerText;
    const booked = row.querySelector('.booked').innerText;
    const price = row.querySelector('.price').innerText;

    updates.push({
      date,
      location_code,
      property_code,
      room_type,
      rooms_available: parseInt(rooms_available, 10),
      booked: parseInt(booked, 10),
      price: parseFloat(price)
    });
  });

  if (updates.length === 0) {
    alert("No rows selected for update.");
    return;
  }
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/availabilities/update`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ updates })
    });
    const result = await response.json();
    alert(result.success || result.message);
    reapplyEditable();
    const selectedLocationCode = document.getElementById('locationCode').value;
    const selectedPropertyCode = document.getElementById('propertyCode').value;
    const selectedRoomType = document.getElementById('roomType').value;
    const startDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
    const endDate = document.getElementById('endDate').value;

    fetchAvailabilities({
      location_code: selectedLocationCode,
      property_code: selectedPropertyCode,
      room_type: selectedRoomType,
      dates: [startDate, endDate]
    });
    rows.forEach(row => row.classList.remove('selected'));

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error updating availabilities:', error);
    alert('Failed to update availabilities');
  }
}

function addEventListenerSafely(elementId, eventType, callback) {
  const element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  if (element) {
    element.addEventListener(eventType, callback);
  } else {
    console.warn(`Element with ID ${elementId} not found. Event listener not attached.`);
  }
}
addEventListenerSafely('searchButton', 'click', () => {
  const selectedLocationCode = document.getElementById('locationCode').value;
  const selectedPropertyCode = document.getElementById('propertyCode').value;
  const selectedRoomType = document.getElementById('roomType').value;

  const startDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
  const endDate = document.getElementById('endDate').value;

  fetchAvailabilities({
    location_code: selectedLocationCode,
    property_code: selectedPropertyCode,
    room_type: selectedRoomType,
    dates: [startDate, endDate]
  });
});

addEventListenerSafely('updateButton', 'click', () => {
  updateSelectedRows();
});

addEventListenerSafely('locationCode', 'change', (event) => {
  const selectedLocationCode = event.target.value;

  if (selectedLocationCode !== 'Any') {
    fetchPropertyCodesByLocation(selectedLocationCode);
  } else {
    const propertyCodeSelect = document.getElementById('propertyCode');
    propertyCodeSelect.innerHTML = `<option value="Any">Select Property</option>`;
  }
});

fetchDistinctValues();


main.js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
  electron: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '.bin', 'electron')
});

function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800, 
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'renderer.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true,  
      contextIsolation: false 
    },
    icon: path.join(__dirname, 'assets', 'icon.png')  
  });

  win.loadFile('index.html');

  win.webContents.openDevTools();
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow(); 

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow();
    }
  });
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

I want to update when ever I click on table cell and not by switching to other activities and then get back to Electron.js app and up date.
